# Using CouchDb on a android phone and mongodb on the server side

Tags: android, mongodb, mobile, couchdb, nosql

I have the following scenario.I need to have an embedded database(nosql) on Android and i have a master database on the server which should ideally be nosql database.There needs to be syncing between the two.All queries from the mobile will go to the iternal database.We have differnt options 
1)Use couchDB on the mobile side and also use couchdb on the server side
2)Use couchDb on the mobile side and use Mongodb on the server side
3)Use sqlLite on the mobile side and use MongoDb/CouchDb on the server side.

Please give your views in evaluating the best option and the benifits/problems of using these approaches.
Note:Currently MongoDb does not support for an embedded database on Android.Also Mongo does not provide the REST APIS and we need to use third paty like MongoLabs and SleepyMongoose

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the methodology you would use to sync changes between the databases especially in the cases in which changes conflict (an update on one side, a delete of the matching record on the other side for example), but it seems like your life will be simpler using the same database on each side.