# synchronize data from cloudant to mlab

Tags: ionic2, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant, mlab

I'm trying to build an ionic 2 application. I'm using PouchDB with Cloudant for data synchronization between offline and online. My problem that I want to synchronize the data present in Cloudant with my other database in mlab.

Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36216260/13860

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/10221815/13860

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connecting mlab database with pouchdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253097/connecting-mlab-database-with-pouchdb)